# Using Android phone as gps?

Tags: gps, android

I need to do a field mapping and i already have the grid (points). I need to put this points in my phone and use my android device to find this points in the field. I won't have any internet connection.

Comment: Why not use qGIS on desktop? In order to help you more, we need to know why you are pursuing a solution that involves unconventional steps like using your phone's GPS to find points.

Comment: judging from the question, he won't be using a desktop as he'll literally be in a field.

Comment: Use gis aplication for android. Qfield, oruxmaps

Comment: i've used this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.xylem.mapin

Comment: Here WeGo Offline Maps https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.here.app.maps&hl=en you can add your lat/lng points online and then switch the app to offline and you can still nagivate to that location.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262127/field-data-collection-for-qgis

Answer (score 3):

There are several apps that will allow you to do this. [Collector for ArcGIS](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/) or [Gaia GPS](https://www.gaiagps.com/) are two that I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

I did this mapping and I succeed on it. To find the points on the field, I created a grid on Qgis and exported the data to an excel table. Then, in the field and with the coordinates, I used the app 'GPS Status' to find the points. The program doesn't show a real-time map like google earth, what can slow down a bit the work, but it's really possible to do a mapping with this method.