# Field data collection for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, data-collection, qfield

I'm new to the open-source GIS world, having abandoned ArcGIS due to costs, and am looking for an OS analog to the Collector app. What I'm seeking to do is collect field data with an Android cell phone (namely points, tracks, polygons to which I can assign some attributes) and import it into QGIS, like I'd have done with Collector and Arc. I've toyed with NextGIS, GeoODK Collect, and QField but they seem crazy confusing to a noob like myself.

Any hints or recommended starting points?

I can get basic GPX data from any old mapping app but I'm looking for something more robust and scalable.

UPDATE: I've gotten QField to the point where I can create an informative map in QGIS and upload it to my phone; the issue now is figuring out how to record GPS tracks and the like. I'm finding the clunky interface (and online documentation) a bit lacking. I gather I can simply draw polygons and lines, but that's not nearly as helpful as being able to log my GPS track. I need this functionality to map logging roads/trails. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you can have a look at Qfield? I don't know much about it myself.

Comment: QField with a little patience works well, take some time to setup and config your workflow, styles and formats. http://www.qfield.org/docs/concepts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[AmigoCollect](https://www.amigocloud.com/en/products/amigocollect/) has open source drivers for QGIS and GDAL that enable you to integrate with QGIS and most open source software GIS directly. Whereas most systems will go through an elaborate export/import process, you can simple use this with a few click.

[This video shows how the QGIS integration works](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=El2-tXZBfKM)

The main differentiator between that and other options include is that AmigoCollect:

- supports simple workflows (e.g. collecting points with geotagged photos) as well as complex ones (e.g. collecting lines and polygons in relationships)
- direct integration with 80+ formats including all the standard GIS ones like Shapefiles, GDBs (File or Enterprise Oracle/SQL server/Postgres/etc), CAD, etc
- online maps and dashboards
- online interface to query data through spatial SQL using PostGIS syntax
- automatic offline support (no need to configure, it just works).

It is SaaS, meaning to use the online service [create a trial](https://www.AmigoCloud.com), download the iPhone/iPad/Android application and use it. This [2 min video shows how to do it](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lj6OeTZgzM8).

When the trial is over you can pay a subscription based on what you want.

Disclaimer: It is my company :)